# A LINQ Challenge

Tags: c#, linq

I have a struct like this:

```
 public struct MyStruct
 {
     public string Name;
     public bool Process;
 }
```

And I have a list of myStruct like this:

> "123", true
>
> "123", false
>
> "234", true
>
> "345", false
>
> "456", true
>
> "456", false

I want to able to use LINQ to return a list like this:

> "123", false
>
> "234", true
>
> "345", false
>
> "456", false

So basically the result I want is a list of distinct names ("123", "234", ...etc) along with the boolean flag and if the names are repeated I need to do an "AND" operation on the flag.

Is there an easy way to do this with one single LINQ statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var result = input.GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                  .Select(gr => new { Name = gr.Key,
                                      All = gr.All(e => e.Process) });
```

Comment: Timwi, that was fast and it's exactly what I'm looking for. I was very close but I didn't get the .All part figure out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct MyStruct
{
     public string Name;
     public bool Process;
}    

public void LinqCellenge()
{
   var sourceList = Enumerable.Empty<MyStruct>();

    var resultList = sourceList
      .GroupBy(item => item.Name, (name, values) => new MyStruct()
        {
          Name = name,
          Flag = values.All(x => x.Flag)
        });
}
```